# how to get input to stretch to 100% in flexbox div with justify-content center

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the input in the snippet below to stretch to 100% of containing button without doing something like `width: 150%`

```css
.explore__column,
.explore__row {
  display: flex;
}

.explore__row {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.search-box__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 3.75rem!important;
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem!important;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box__item.search-box__active {
  border-top: 2px solid #4f9bc9;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.search-box__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 3.75rem!important;
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem!important;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="explore__row"><button class="search-box__item search-box__active" type="button"><div class="search-box__translate"><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="overflow: visible;"><use xlink:href="#icon-Plan" style="overflow: visible;"></use></svg></div><div class="search-box__fade
"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" placeholder="search Plans"></div><h2>One</h2></button><button class="search-box__item" type="button"><div class="search-box__translate"><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="overflow: visible;"><use xlink:href="#icon-BusinessUnit" style="overflow: visible;"></use></svg></div><div class="search-box__fade"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" placeholder="search Business Units"></div><h2>Two</h2></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot use `<div>` inside a button element (why would you use a button in this case in the first place? It made your content wiggle whenever you clicked on it)
2. Just add a width of 100% to the input as well as its parent, and add `box-sizing: border-box` in order to take padding into account as well.

```css
.explore__column,
.explore__row {
  display: flex;
}

.explore__row {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.search-box__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 3.75rem!important;
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem!important;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.search-box__item.search-box__active {
  border-top: 2px solid #4f9bc9;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.search-box__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 3.75rem!important;
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem!important;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box__fade,
input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="explore__row">
  <div class="search-box__item search-box__active" type="button">
    <div class="search-box__translate">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="overflow: visible;"><use xlink:href="#icon-Plan" style="overflow: visible;"></use></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box__fade">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" placeholder="search Plans"></div>
    <h2>One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="search-box__item" type="button">
    <div class="search-box__translate">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="overflow: visible;"><use xlink:href="#icon-BusinessUnit" style="overflow: visible;"></use></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box__fade">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" placeholder="search Business Units">
    </div>
    <h2>Two</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used a button so it is tabable and also for accessibility, I would have thought it should be a button

Comment: Well, a button is something that can be clicked and usually triggers an action. And a button shouldn't include an input field, as focusing the input via clicking would also click the button. Inputs can receive focus/be tabbed into on their own, so they are accessible already.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `flex-direction: column` from your `.search-box__item` element. And add this code snippet:

```
.search-box__item {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.search-box__fade {
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```